Control if output from power query is empty
I have a query which combines a bunch of headerless tables in a workbook:
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(),
    #"Kept Range of Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Name] <> "Summary")),
    #"Expanded Content" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Kept Range of Rows", "Content", {"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4"}, {"Content.Column1", "Content.Column2", "Content.Column3", "Content.Column4"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded Content", each ([Content.Column2] <> null)),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Name", "Content.Column1", "Content.Column2", "Content.Column3", "Content.Column4"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{"Content.Column1"}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Columns",{{"Content.Column6", Order.Ascending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows"

This works fine except when all the source tables are empty. Then the query clears the data and formatting from the line above the output table, and inserts the previous last line of the output table there...
Is there a way to prevent this from happening?
I was thinking of checking whether the output table is empty, and if so inserting a row of null values, or dashes, or whatever, but I have little to no idea about how to go about this...
Can someone here give me a clue on how to solve the problem?

sounds like you should add an if statement between #"Kept Range of Rows" and #"Expanded Content". This would be done with the advanced editor. Do a google search on power query dax if.
